# kafka connector to read from csv and convert in to avro

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

is there any kafka connector which read from csv and converts into Avro before pushing it to the topic?

I have gone through the well know https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir, but it only reads and pushes to the topic. 
I am planning to modify the code base for my custom use but before i make the changes, i just wanted to check if there already such connector available.

Answer (score 2):

`kafka-connect-spooldir` does do exactly what you describe. When you run it, you just need to set Kafka Connect to use Avro converter. For example:

```
"key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
```

See https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained for more information about how converters and connectors relate.

---

Edit in response to your comment:

> When i am using kafka-console-consumer i am seeing data as
>
> `103693(2018-03-11T09:19:17Z Sugar - assa8.7`
>
> when i am using kafka-avro-console-consumer format is
>
> `{"order_id":{"string":"1035"},"customer_id":{"string":"93"},"order_ts":{"string":"2018-03-11T09:19:17Z"},"product":{"string":"Sugar - assa"},"order_total_usd":{"string":"8.7"}}.`

This shows that it *is* Avro data on your topic. The whole point of `kafka-avro-console-consumer` is that it decodes the binary Avro data and renders it in plain format. The output from `kafka-console-consumer` shows the raw Avro, parts of which may look human-readable (`Sugar - assa`) but others clearly not (`103693`)

Comment: :Provided link helped to understand the flow. I am able to see data in kafka topic. However, i wanted to check if it really got written in avro format. When i am using kafka-console-consumer i am seeing data as :103693(2018-03-11T09:19:17Z Sugar - assa8.7 when i am using kafka-avro-console-consumer(with or without schema registry url) format is {"order_id":{"string":"1035"},"customer_id":{"string":"93"},"order_ts":{"string":"2018-03-11T09:19:17Z"},"product":{"string":"Sugar - assa"},"order_total_usd":{"string":"8.7"}}. I was expecting data to be in binary and not human-readable format.

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your comment. The long and short of it is that you *do* have Avro data on your topic.

Comment: @Manu Use `kafka-console-consumer` to get binary. The avro consumer will deserialize and format to JSON